# Python ZeroMQ broadcasting messages

Tags: python, zeromq, fault-tolerance

I am going to implement a Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance ( PBFT ).

Hence, I am going to have multiple processes, P0 is going to initialize a round, by sending a first message.

Is it possible to broadcast a message to all other processes using ZeroMQ?

With **`PUB/SUB`**, I need to bind/connect sockets. But I am going to take the number of processes as arguments, it seems impractical to connect all other ports ( I do not know if this is possible ?! ). I could not write any code since I am stuck in the beginning.

Basically, if I find the way to connect processes I will do this:

The proposer selects a random message m and sends it to all validators.
Upon reception each validator sends the message to other validators and the proposer.
If a validator (or proposer) receives at least 2k messages from the other
processes that are identical to its own it proceeds to the next
round of the consensus algorithm.

One more addition: Processes are going to communicate with each other directly. But connecting to all other processes sockets with REQ/REP is not clever, though.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is it possible to broadcast a message to all other processes using ZeroMQ?*

### Oh sure, it is .

This is exactly why all messaging and signalling tools, like ZeroMQ, nanomsg and others, were developed for.

The beauty and the trick of PBFT is, that there ought be zero-singular point of defection, ought be there?

So any other approach, but the circular-message actually being sent and delivered one-after-another, will not help the PBFT, will it?

Feel free to sketch the solution, the port-mapping will not be your main issue in this. ZeroMQ can **`.bind()`**/**`.connect()`** in a very flexible manner. One may even create an ad-hoc, non-persistent, connectivity setup in a similarly circular-manner, if ports are indeed a scarce resource, so get a bit more courage and go get it done **`:o)`**

Comment: Actually I set up a solution but this zmq stuck me here. So, which method should I use? Pub/sub? But how do I bind them?

Comment: Great, the first step was done, so keep walking step after step. Best update your post with code you have already designed ( MCVE-example is the StackOverflow Standard Policy in this, so feel free to re-read details how to ask MCVE-based high quality posts, if not sure how to proceed  ) or open another, code-issue specific MCVE-based question on parts, that do not follow the documented and published API. This is how StackOverflow works. That's fair, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to clarify my solution.